# PostgreSQL global transaction and restore point in time

Tags: postgresql

I'm searching for some solution where I can click 'open transaction' button and from now on whatever is done on database is stored in memory. Then I can hit 'revert' or 'commit' when I'm done.

We have really hard testing path. To test single action we have to prepare a lot of data and reverting this action is really hard or impossible.
What I want to achieve is ability to test solution/action/test scenario and go back with database after im done.

1. Open transaction or create some recovery point
2. Do tests (this can be done by multiple http requests and db connections)
3. Restore recovery point

Obviously i'm not talking about transactions done in single connection with `BEGIN;` `COMMIT;` and `ROLLBACK;`

Answer (score 2):

How much test data are we talking about? One possible thing I can think of:

Create a database that contains your test data.

```
create database base_test
    owner = ....
    is_template = true;
```

Then create whatever you need in the `base_test`.

When you start your test, clone that database using:

```
create database test_db
   template = base_test
   owner = ...;
```

Then run the tests on `test_db`.

Once your tests are done, you can throw away `test_db` and re-create it. Any change to the structure or content of the test data must be done in `base_test`.

The speed of cloning the DB depends on the size, it is essentially just a file copy. However if your test data is several GB, this might not be feasible.

Comment: About 2GB. Problem with this method is that you always go back to point 0. Would be nice to have such thing on demand 'Hmm, I will do crazy stuff. > Hit setRestorePointBtn'. It also require to: disconnect users from database, delete it, create one using template.